# How to reproduce a Modernizr custom build given the build string

Tags: modernizr

Here is my situation:

I have this modernizr js file that reads

```
Build: http://www.modernizr.com/download/#-cssanimations-iepp-cssclasses-testprop-testallprops-domprefixes-load
```

To redownload this build (i thought i could just paste the url, but it didnt work.

When i went to the site, it lets you compose your build but you have use human readable features /components/names, but after you build it, the file has these abbreviations.

Is there a way to know what the abbreviations of the listed components on the site?

Answer (score 0):

There is a server issue on the modernizr site (sorry about that!). It is redirecting any http traffic to the https homepage. In the mean time, just throw an `s` on it - [like so](https://modernizr.com/download/?cssanimations-domprefixes-setclasses-testallprops-testprop)